# Do i have to use delegate when I want to change something from on VC in another VC ? SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am doing some excercises now. For example I create two view controllers in storybard  and I want to change color for example from VC2 in VC1 by clicking button. In this situation delegate is needed or is other way to do it?

Comment: Also see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fbTHFH3tl4)

Comment: I just doing it:) txh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, yes. But that depends . You can use NotificationCenter, you can use "prepare" function. The delegate is the most common option here. In your case:

```
protocol ChangeButtonColorDelegate {
    func changeButtonColor() 
}

class VC1 : ChangeButtonColorDelegate... {
    func changeButtonColor() {
        /* change button color here */
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "goto_vc2") {
            (segue.dest as! VC2).delegate = self 
        }
    }
}

class VC2 : ... {
    var delegate : ChangeButtonColorDelegate!
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It cleared me everything:) Clear and quick!

Comment: Please mark this answer as the right answer so :)

Comment: its the check mark below the counter